# Are alternate names in Facebook searchable?

Tags: facebook

I mean that, if I add an alternate name to my Facebook account, will my profile be found by others even when they search by my alternate name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This is exactly the reason they added this feature. 
https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=98445832130